# UIButton add target without sender

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a `UIDatePicker`. After a date is selected I call this method

```
func goToNextScreen(selectedDate: Date) {
    //...
}
```

Now I have added a `UIButton`. In that button action I want to call the same method `goToNextScreen` without any date value. Date value is optional in next screen. I tried the following code

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToNextScreen), for: .touchUpInside)//goToNextScreen(_:)

@objc func goToNextScreen(selectedDate: Date? = nil) {
    //...
}
```

When the button is tapped the app crashes.

**How to solve this without adding another method? If it is not possible why my approach doesn't work**

Comment: Use `Any` as type of parameter and check inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Any` as `sender` type and casting to `Date` works

```
//add button Target
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToNextScreen(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

//Call with date value
goToNextScreen(Date())

@objc func goToNextScreen(_ selectedDate: Any) {
    nextVC.date = selectedDate as? Date
    //...
}
```

Comment: This actually works but I don't think it's the best solution. In the other case `selectedDate` will be a variable of type `UIButton` which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio When `selectedDate` is `UIButton`, `selectedDate as? Date` fails and `nextVC.date` will be `nil`. Thats what I need

Comment: Yes, I got what you mean and it works, I’m just saying that on a logic point of view I don’t really like this approach

Answer (score 4):

What is happening here is, the button's internal logic is trying to pass the sender, which is a `UIButton` into your method's `Date` parameter. However, the sender parameter won't get passed if your method don't have any arguments.

Optional parameters don't really work in this situation. What you can do however, is to create another parameterless overload for `goToNextScreen`:

```
@objc func goToNextScreen() {
    goToNextScreen(selectedDate: nil)
}
```

And change

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToNextScreen), for: .touchUpInside)
```

to

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToNextScreen as () -> Void), for: .touchUpInside)
```

so that it different between the two overloads.

Note that the reason why just writing `#selector(goToNextScreen)` is ambiguous is because you have two methods named `goToNextScreen`, and Swift needs to resolve to one of them. But it can't with just the name. Here is a similar situation:

```
class Foo {
    @objc func f() {}
    func f(x: Int) {}
    let selector: Selector = #selector(f) // ambiguous use of f
}
```

Edit: You can't really do this without creating another method. Selectors are inflexible things.

Comment: awesome elaboration +1

Comment: Maybe he downvoted because he asked not to write another method, which is impossible in this case

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio Ah I didn't realise OP edited the question before I post the answer! Oh well.

Comment: @Sweeper If I must have to add another method, Why I need `goToNextScreen as () -> Void` instead of `goToNextScreen`

Comment: @arunsiva Otherwise you can't differentiate between the two overloads with just `goToNextScreen`. It will produce the error "Ambiguous use of ...".

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible in this case re-use the same method. You should create a new one without parameters or whose parameters are `UIButton` (or a more generic type, often is `Any`) and the `UIEvent`. 
Here's the explanation of the Target-Action mechanism: [UIControl](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol).

Answer (score 1):

I thought you've to try this

```
var selectedDate = Date()
```

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToNextScreen), for: .touchUpInside)//goToNextScreen(_:)
```

```
@objc func goToNextScreen(_ sender: UIButton) 
{     

   selectedDate ?? self.datePickerDate : Date()    
}
```

Comment: I thought using an instance property is unnecessary

Answer (score -2):

`sender` paramter of `UIButton` is casted to `Date` which is reason of crash , it should be a `UIButton`

```
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnClicked), for: .touchUpInside)//goToNextScreen(_:) 

@objc func btnClicked(_ sender:UIButton)  {
  // call next here
  goToNextScreen()
}
func goToNextScreen(_ selectedDate: Date? = nil) {
   if let date = selectedDate { }
}
```